a4988 pulldown resistor necessary for ms1 ms2 ms3
Im using a4988 and are constructing a small pcb carrier for multiple a4988. I have a question on how to connect ms1, ms2, ms3. Do I need pulldown resistors after my DIP switch? Is it necessary? When I used a4988 I have simply not connected the ms1, ms2, ms3 at all and kept them floating.
If I need pulldown is this the correct way in the schematic? maybe 10k?

Or can I just leave them like in the image below


If you look at the data sheet, the microstep select pins have internal pull-dows, so they can be left floating.

Great. I read this thread:
https://community.libre.space/t/a4988-ms1-ms3-pull-downs-or-lack-of/2000
But according to this this datasheet it seems to be the case that it has internal pull down
https://w.electrodragon.com/w/A4988
